# How to access the UIView from a UIActivity custom object?

Tags: uiactivity

I am using UIActivityViewController with custom activities and I want to do access the view of the activity that was selected. Is there any way to do this ?

According to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivity_Class/) there is `activityImage` for accessing the UIImage but nothing for the view.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Apple is not yet available
https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/86293

I filed an enhancement ticket #23496617